# Looking for tricks to fix New-PSSession errorcode 0x80090322

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

`New-PSSession` is pretty straight forward and for the most part works, but it's still a tad dodgy in the environment I am working within. The company I do side sysadmin for has a strange situation where we have two VPNs floating around with most of the employees working remote. Now for the most part, I understand that if their registered IP still hasn't updated (Due to lag, dropping and reconnecting, or those two VPN's fighting each-other,) I know `PSSession` won't work immediately. That's all fine. What I don't quite get however are the cases where remote tools, and interacting with their machine via `\\CName\c$` work fine, but powershell still fails. Poking around enabling psremoting tends to fix this, but in our environment this requires elevated credentials, which most employees do not posses. Currently I'm in the middle of an annoying repair project for microsoft's software center, and a few machines just refuse any attempts for my tools to open a session with them to uninstall, reinstall, or otherwise repair components.

I'm wondering if people have any tricks up their sleeves or know of a good PSRemoting thread (I'm very new here, and a bit to powershell as well,) about other methods, either through command line remotely or otherwise. I'm new to the industry and I can't quite seem to puzzle this out. Attached is an image that I'm sure a lot of people have seen before when it comes to this error.

[image: PS_Session Kerberos error]

Am I boned in needing to enable-pssession on everyone's machines? They don't let me touch group policies so I can't quite use that to make anything standard either. gpupdate/force on some of those machines tends to freak out due to how terrible our deployment of configurationmanager/software center is, too...

Comment: "They don't let me touch group policies" - will they let you use _any_ remote mass-management tools (like SCCM)? You'll need to at very least run `winrm quickconfig` to have the machines enable the default WinRM listener and register SPNs on each target machine

Comment: Sadly no. Very much in a situation where I'm paid to create and push tickets, but the sccm team comes to me to fix their issues. All I have access to is third party software(https://github.com/rzander/sccmclictr) our 2016 AD server, which doesn't have SCCM loaded on my profile, and whatever I can think of or whip up in powershell's IDE/cmd.

Hands are pretty tied at the moment, but I'll take a look to see if I can do winrm quickconfig another way, thanks

Comment: That sucks, but it really sounds like you need to explain the problem and it's implications to the client and ask them whether they prefer 1) Authorizing you to make the change, 2) Making the change themselves or 3) Accepting getting limited value out of your engagement. This is not a technical problem :)

Comment: We have an alarming failure rate for the software center and deployments in general - every machine should be nice and happy when accepting admin credentials while on the network via hardline or vpn, but they just don't. Past fiddling around with winrm quickconfig, are there any other avenues I should look in to? If no, I'm fine with 3, it's just a bit frustrating is all! Thanks though, I'll definitely push to get after that SCCM tool again. About two years ago we used it, or at least something similar as a ticketing system, but it's been so long that the lines are bluring.

Comment: "are there any other avenues I should look in to" - from the information you've presented, no. I mean, there's no mystery to enabling WinRM/PSRP everywhere ("Run Enable-PSRemoting or winrm qc with privileges, on every machine"), it's very straightforward and well documented - but no amount of technical documentation or remoting scripts or tools can make up for your client not engaging in maintaining their infrastructure and management tools :)